# Why is Local Binary Pattern affected by scaling?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

I found that the local binary pattern in scikit-image is affected by re-scaling the image, but I was not expecting this. Since the LBP just involves greater/less than comparisons between nearby pixels, I thought a linear transformation would not affect things.

```
import numpy as np
import skimage
from skimage.feature import local_binary_pattern

im = skimage.data.cell()

out_im = local_binary_pattern(im, 16, 2, method='uniform')
out_im = out_im[20:-20, 20:-20] # remove edges
counts,bins = np.histogram(out_im)
print('counts=',counts)
print('bins=',bins)
```

This gives me

```
counts= [   896   2743   9555  14928 108466  94041  28682  14703   8728  33458]
bins= [ 0.   1.7  3.4  5.1  6.8  8.5 10.2 11.9 13.6 15.3 17. ]
```

But if I normalize the image:

```
im = (im-im.min())/(im.max()-im.min())
```

Then I get:

```
counts= [   937   2716   9504  16263 109302  92114  27753  14248   8667  34696]
bins= [ 0.   1.7  3.4  5.1  6.8  8.5 10.2 11.9 13.6 15.3 17. ]
```

Can someone explain why? The original image has values between 0 and 255.

Comment: The comparison is done on fixed positions. When you resize the image, you will compare with different content (the same fixed positions have a different content now)

Comment: I’m not resizing, just mapping the intensity to the range [0,1]

Comment: Can you tell min and max values? What happens in the image border, if 0 neighborhood is assumed outside of the image you will have additional "equal" patterns after scaling min to 0

Comment: I added them in the post. They are 0 and 255. I also removed the edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that there is no difference when there are only 4 points in the kernel, which correspond to up/down/left/right. This suggests that the difference arises due to the floating point interpolation when the points  are located at non-integer coordinates. I'm guessing that the floating point calculations occasionally mess up the greater/equal comparisons, leading to slightly different histograms.

Comment: I think you're right, this is a floating-point rounding error issue. Note that the scaling itself already introduces rounding errors.

Comment: There are sometimes even differences when multiplying an integer image by another integer. The image remains integer-type, but if the number of kernel points is not 4, the floating point interpolation sometimes changes things.